# Python error: Nonetype object not subscriptable, when loading JSON into variables

Tags: python, json

I have a program where I am reading in a JSON file, and executing some SQL based on parameters specified in the file. The

```
load_json_file()
```

method loads the json file to a Python object first (not seen here but works correctly)
  The issue is with the piece of the code here:

```
class TestAutomation:

def __init__(self):
    self.load_json_file()

# connect to Teradata and load session to be used for execution
def connection(self):
    con = self.load_json_file()
    cfg_dsn = con['config']['dsn']
    cfg_usr = con['config']['username']
    cfg_pwd = con['config']['password']
    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="DataAnalysis", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
    session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn=cfg_dsn, username=cfg_usr, password=cfg_pwd)

    return session
```

the **init_** method first loads the JSON file, and then I store that in 'con'. I am getting an error though that reads:

```
cfg_dsn = con['config']['dsn']
E   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "config":{
                                "src":"C:/Dev\\path",              
                                "dsn":"XYZ",
                                "sheet_name":"test",
                                "out_file_prefix":"C:/Dev\\test\\OutputFile_",                       
                                "password":"pw123",
                                "username":"user123",
                                "start_table":"11",
                                "end_table":"26",
                                "skip_table":"1,13,17",
                                "spot_check_table":"77"
    }
}
```

the load_json_file() is defined like this:

```
def load_json_file(self):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + '\dwconfig.json'):
        with open('dwconfig.json') as json_data_file:
            cfg_data = json.load(json_data_file)
        return cfg_data
```

Any ideas why I am seeing the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It would be especially useful to see how `load_json_file` is defined.

Comment: Either `con` is None, or `con['config']` is None.

Comment: Clearly con is None, otherwise you would get a KeyError (tested). `Not subscriptable` means that you cannot "index" (use the object[index]) notation on it ; that you cannot iterate this way.

Comment: `load_json_file()` will return None if the filename does not exist (or is unreadable).

Comment: As John Gordon pointed, you do not treat the case where `os.path.isfile` is false. If a function doesn't return anything, it does in fact return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that you're checking if the configuration file exists, then read it.

If it doesn't, your function returns `None`. This is wrong in many ways because `os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])` can return an incorrect value, for instance if the command is run with just the base name, found through the system path (`$0` returns the full path in bash but not in python or C).

That's not how you get the directory of the current command.

(plus afterwards you're going to do `with open('dwconfig.json') as json_data_file:` which is now the name of the file, without the full path, wrong again)

I would skip this test, but compute the config file path properly. And if it doesn't exist, let the program crash instead of returning `None` that will crash later.

```
def load_json_file(self):
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'dwconfig.json')) as json_data_file:
        cfg_data = json.load(json_data_file)
    return cfg_data
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have resolved the issue.  Its weird, I have another function where I am reading different pieces of that JSON file into variables, and it worked fine.  This isprobably a better way to go though

Answer (score 0):

So... `cfg_dsn = con['config']['dsn']`

something in there is set to None

you could be safe and write it like

`(con or {}).get('config',{}).get('dsn')`

or make your data correct.

Comment: Thanks Grady.  I am not sure why its set to None. You can see in the JSON file above that dsn has a value.

Comment: log out: self.load_json_file()